# How to say abstract noun + manifested?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would you say "abstract concept" + manifested, as in, made manifest?

I would like the describe abstract concepts/theoretical ideals, realised in the material world.

For example, a projection of God wandering our world might be described as "perfection manifested"

To say this in latin, would a more natural phrasing be "the manifestation of perfection" (using "manifestatio")

Or is there a way to apply the "past"-form "manifested" to perfectio directly, as in English? (I'm not sure what this grammatical construct is called in English)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to express the word manifested, you can either use the **adjective** *manifestus* or a **perfect past participle**.

Here's the adjective *manifesus*:

**Singular:**

| Case | Masculine | Feminine | Neuter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nom. | manifēstus | manifēsta | manifēstum |
| Gen. | manifēstī | manifēstae | manifēstī |
| Dat. | manifēstō | manifēstae | manifēstō |
| Acc. | manifēstum | manifēstam | manifēstum |
| Abl. | manifēstō | manifēstā | manifēstō |
| Voc. | manifēste | manifēsta | manifēstum |

**Plural:**

| Case | Masculine | Feminine | Neuter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nom. | manifēstī | manifēstae | manifēsta |
| Gen. | manifēstōrum | manifēstārum | manifēstōrum |
| Dat. | manifēstīs | manifēstīs | manifēstīs |
| Acc. | manifēstōs | manifēstās | manifēsta |
| Abl. | manifēstīs | manifēstīs | manifēstīs |
| Voc. | manifēstī | manifēstae | manifēsta |

Whether it's and adjective or a participle it has to agree in number, case, and gender with the noun it modifies. For example if you want to speak of "perfection manifested" in the nominative case, it would have to be the singular, feminine form to agree with *perfectio*:

> perfectio manifesta

As for the participles, @brianpck pointed out in a comment that the verb *manifesto* is post-classical, so its perfect passive participle *manifestatus* (not to be confused with the adjective *manifestus*) is rarely used. Perhaps a better choice would be *revelo*, *patefacio*, or *ostendo*:

> [ostendere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ostendere&la=la#lexicon): to stretch out, spread before, expose to view, show, point
> out, exhibit, display
>
> [patefacere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=patefacere&la=la#lexicon): to disclose, expose, detect, bring to light
>
> [revelare](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=revelare&la=la#lexicon): to unveil, uncover, lay bare

Participles are declined similar to the way that adjectives are:

**Singular:**

| Case | Masculine | Feminine | Neuter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nom. | ostentus | ostenta | ostentum |
| Gen. | ostentī | ostentae | ostentī |
| Dat. | ostentō | ostentae | ostentō |
| Acc. | ostentum | ostentam | ostentum |
| Abl. | ostentō | ostentā | ostentō |
| Voc. | ostente | ostenta | ostentum |

**Plural:**

| Case | Masculine | Feminine | Neuter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nom. | ostentī | ostentae | ostenta |
| Gen. | ostentōrum | ostentārum | ostentōrum |
| Dat. | ostentīs | ostentīs | ostentīs |
| Acc. | ostentōs | ostentās | ostenta |
| Abl. | ostentīs | ostentīs | ostentīs |
| Voc. | ostentī | ostentae | ostenta |

Comment: Oh and then you attach it to the abstract noun as if it were an adjective? "manifestata perfectio"?

Comment: @theonlygusti. Yes, I'm about to update my answer to give more info.

Comment: Keep in mind that *manifesto* is a pretty uncommon word: L&S marks it as "poetic" and "post-classical." I would probably use a word like *revelo*, *patefacio*, or *ostendo*.

Comment: @brianpck Thanks for the information. Do you know if incarnate existed in classical latin?

Comment: @brianpck. Good call. I updated my answer to address that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, while *manifestare* may be rare, *manifestus* is not, and it may be fitting here too.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel. Thanks! I included _manifestus_ in the answer.